# What happens when you specify two width sizes in Masonry?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

I am wondering what happens in the 5th div below:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div> //This one...
  ...
</div>
```

The JS is:

```
.grid-sizer,
.grid-item { width: 22%; }

.gutter-sizer { width: 4%; }

.grid-item--width2 { width: 48%; }
```

It seems to me that we are setting the width twice - 22% and 48%. Am I understanding that correctly?
This is from the Masonry tutorials:
https://masonry.desandro.com/options.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The block `.grid-item--width2 { width: 48%; }` will apply. There can't be "two widths", the later one will take precedence because they have same specificity (you can read about selectors specificity [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity))

Comment: Thank you for this response. Am I right to think that this line would behave the same if it only had .grid-item--width2 as the class?
Is there any reason why both are there?

Comment: Yes, you are. There may be other styles associated with `.grid-item` and `.grid-item--width2` is there only to override the width.

Comment: Thanks Lucas.. I'm somewhat disappointed in that case that Masonry documentation would have code like that. It's somewhat misleading. That said, Masonry is epic!